# about send mail symfony2, swiftmailer and ovh

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have a problem of send mail, the mail isn't always send :
sometimes reply with successful sent (and I find it in mailbox)
sometimes reply with failed sent

This's the error message :

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message «  »
```

This's the content of log file :

```
[2014-02-27 23:13:43] request.INFO: Matched route "ws_front_message_send" (parameters: "_controller": "Ws\Bundle\MailerBundle\Controller\SendController::messageAction", "domain": "saci.com.tn", "_route": "ws_front_message_send") [] []
[2014-02-27 23:13:43] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2014-02-27 23:13:44] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Swift_TransportException: "Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message """ at /homez.755/sacinrgm/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 386 {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code \"\", with message \"\" at /homez.755/sacinrgm/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386)"} []
[2014-02-27 23:13:44] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
     # smtp ovh parametres
     mailer_transport: smtp
     mailer_port: 465
     mailer_encryption: ssl
     mailer_auth_mode: login
     mailer_host: ssl0.ovh.net
     mailer_user: **************
     mailer_password: **************
```

my action in controller:

```
public function messageAction(Request $request) {
    $message = new Message();
    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');

    $form = $this->createForm(new MessageCreate(), $message, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('ws_front_message_send'),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'attr' => array('id' => 'form')
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $mailFrom = $message->getEmail();
    $mailTo = $this->container->getParameter('mailer_customer');

    $mail = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Contact ' . $message->getCountry() . ' from Saci')
            ->setFrom($mailFrom)
            ->setTo($mailTo)
            ->setBody($this->renderView('WsMailerBundle:Email:message.html.twig', array('message' => $message)), 'text/html');

    $mailer->send($mail);

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set(
            'succes', 'contact.msg_after_send');


    return $this->redirect($this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a check to see if $mailFrom is null, not likely the issue but still not a bad practice.

Comment: i'm sure about $mailFrom, but i don't understand why the mail isn't always successfuly send.

Answer (score 0):

I you have trouble with email and spam with ovh, siwftmailer and fosUserBundle,

please consider adding this in your config.yml

```
fos_user:
    from_email:
            address:        noreply@yourdomain.com
            sender_name:
```

yourname

If you don't do this, fos user bundle will send the email with noreply@exemple.com and OVH flag this as spam.

source: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md